# What would be the Regex to match following 6 digit numbers?

Tags: java, regex

The numbers should be 6 digit and of the form 0x0x0x or x0x0x0, where x can be any digit from 1 to 9.
Ex - 202020, 030303, 808080, etc.

I have this regex that matches numbers with alternative 0 and 1s, cannot make it work for the above use case

```
\b(?!\d*(\d)\1)[10]+\b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to capture the repeating part.
Then check if the back reference to group 1 is repeated.

```
\b(0[1-9]|[1-9]0)\1{2}\b
```

Comment: \d also contains the 0, so it is wrong, it should be [1-9]

Comment: Indeed, fixed it

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind repeating both "forms", an alternation is probably the most straightforward solution:

```
\b(?:([1-9])0\10\10|0([1-9])0\20\2)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/R7fAbh/1